# Asked to review my own question

Tags: bug, status-completed

Over on Mathematica.se, I was recently asked to review my own answer:

[image]

which seems like a bug in the review process.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on the main meta site?  I assume this applies to all SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I debated that, and figured at least initially posting it here was better. But, if it needs to go over there, I can put it there.

Comment: Leave it here; I'm not certain.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard exactly my problem, so I erred on the side of caution and less spam. :)

Comment: Now how do we get journals to ask me to review my own papers?

Comment: You should probably tag it as [meta-tag:bug]... It clearly isn't the expected behaviour (in some sense), and the bug tag is monitored by the team more closely than support. If this is the intended behaviour, worst case you'll get a [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: @R.M done. more characters required to post this message. :)

Comment: @R.M self review of papers would be nice: this paper is _eminently_ worthy of publication! :)

Comment: But even better would be self-review of funding requests. ;-)

Comment: status-completed per [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165557). Closing as TL so that the damned bot doesn't bump it up in the future...

Comment: @rm-rf you could have answered it, too. :)

Comment: Well, yeah... but why not take the path of least work? ;)